# Caller ID for forwarded calls

Tags: applications, caller-id, motorola-moto-g

Let's say I have a fixed line phone, say 2xxxxxxx1. I have set this phone to forward all calls to my Moto G, say 9xxxxxxxx2. Now whenever I receive a call that was forwarded, I see two numbers in the caller Id. Say the original caller was 9xxxxxxxx3, then I see the caller id as 9xxxxxxxx32xxxxxxx1, i.e. the actual caller's number, appended by the number that forwarded the call to me.

I understand this can be a great feature to know the actual caller and the forwarder. But, it does not go well with the contacts and apps like True Caller. Also It becomes a pain to quickly save the received call to contacts.

Is there a way I could completely get rid of the forwarder's details from the caller id? Does it happen on all android phones? Is it specific to Moto G, or the OS it is running? Can it be carrier specific? Does anybody know an app that could override the default phone app and provides what I want?

PS: I am having a Moto G Dual Sim in India, running one SIM on Loop carrier, same issue when I tried a Tata carrier. The fixed land line that forwards to my Moto G is run by MTNL

Comment: I think it's very likely that this is a carrier-dependent question and you should consult you carrier. I've never seen or heard about this kind of behaviour. Maybe you could test it by inserting the SIM in another phone, maybe even one with a different OS?

Comment: Caller Forwarding for the provider here (in US) is through the providers network still. Changing the data on the phone sends the change to the cell tower to be recorded there. When a call was forewarded to a landline, I was still being charged for Mobile minutes on the original Cell call.  It was just assumed that the forewarding was entirely being done on the cell network. In both where  the same company provided the landline, and where it was over cable broadband (using thier voip).  So it very well could be "through the 2 numbers" in the cell networks routing.

Comment: @onik Even though the carrier is responsible for providing the caller ID number, there could be a way of working around it using an app on the phone to recognise and strip the forwarding number.

Comment: @onik, yes I would be doing that experiment, but thought someone might have done this already. I am kind of sure there must be an app already that does this, not sure how to search it out